# Why Values of Justify-Content not working when applied on container

Tags: css, flexbox

I hope YOU guys are doing good

I have just started learning Flexbox from CSS Tricks and some YT channels.
But when I used `justify-content:space-around | space-between | space-evenly`. None of them seems to work out.

And I could not find out the problem.
I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out.

```css
.container-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    // flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
 <html>   
    <body>
    <div class="container-1"> 
            <div class="item-1">
                <h1>
                    Box One
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-2">
                <h1>
                    Box Second
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="Item-3">
                <h1>
                    Box Third
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's working as it should - if you want to force see it add css `.item-1, .item-2, .Item-3 {  width: 20%; }`

Comment: please create snippet

Comment: Thanks Bro it worked when i applied "width 20% on all items"
But it is not working when width is 40% because i think its all the space on the webpage.